# create and initialize grid(matrix) 100x100 wih numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am doing a task to simulate Schelling's Model of Segregation.

Now I would like to know the following:

1)how do I generate a 2d matrix(grid) with 100x100cells using numpy

2) how to fill the matrix with 40% of Agents A with 1; 40% of Agents B with 2; and the 20% is empty which is 0. The agents are randomly placed.

I know that there are numpy.ones: numpy.zeroes numpy.array but I don't know how  to to create such 2d matrix and fill it randomly with certain values. How to iterate?

Could some maybe help me?

Thanks!

Comment: How many minutes did you spent with the docs? You visited the parts about array-creation, array-indexing and the random module? What kind of idea do you have in mind? As presented: you described what you want given some lib, but not much of own approaches.

Comment: @sascha Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of approaches with all it's pros and cons. I'm not going to list them all.

This one should be easy to reason about and it's not the slowest, but probably also not the fastest, as we use two fancy-indexing steps (one more reason here to actually read the documentation!):

#### Code

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
a, b, c = 0.4, 0.4, 0.2

def build_mat(N, a, b, c):
    n_a = int(N * N * a)
    n_b = int(N * N * b)
    n_c = N - n_a - n_b

    rng_nonzero_inds_1d = np.random.choice(N*N, n_a + n_b, replace=False)

    mat = np.zeros(N*N)
    mat[rng_nonzero_inds_1d[:n_a]] = 1
    mat[rng_nonzero_inds_1d[n_a:]] = 2

    return mat.reshape((N,N))

mat = build_mat(N, a, b, c)
print('A: ', np.count_nonzero(mat==1))
print('B: ', np.count_nonzero(mat==2))
print('C: ', np.count_nonzero(mat==0))
print(mat)
```

#### Output

```
A:  40
B:  40
C:  20
[[ 1.  1.  2.  0.  2.  1.  0.  2.  1.  2.]
 [ 2.  1.  2.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  2.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  1.  1.  2.  0.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 1.  0.  2.  1.  2.  2.  0.  1.  2.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  1.  1.  2.  1.  2.  1.  2.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  1.  2.  2.  1.  1.  2.  2.  1.]
 [ 0.  2.  1.  1.  2.  1.  1.  2.  0.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.  1.  2.  1.  2.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  2.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  2.  2.  1.  2.  2.  0.  0.  1.]]
```